# PC Remote Desktop / Remote Control Software

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

Could you please suggest me a software having the following feature

- Can access the all the machines in a network
- If the server program is installed in a machine, I will be able to control the client machine
- Access the client machine
- Access the client machine without knowing the user of client machine
- View the desktop of client machine
- Start or stop programs of client machine

Comment: The title ask for network monitoring, but the features describes Remote Desktop like VNC

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're looking for a VNC Server/Client setup. There are a few options when it comes to which client/server software you use, but I personally would opt for Ultra VNC, which is available from here: http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/ultravnc.html.

VNC is unencrypted by default, so passwords etc are sent in plaintext - so it might be a good idea to use an encryption plugin. This URL: http://www.uvnc.com/downloads/encryption-plugins/87-encryption-plugins.html contains some information on that.